# Store DF variable in a vector (issue with quotes)

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a df with variables like this:

```
v1  letters
1   "A","B"
2   "C","D"
3   "E","F"
```

Using tidyverse I filter the df for v1 = 1 and I try to store the variable "letters" in a vector:

```
vect <- c(letters)

However I get "\"A\",\"B\""
```

How can I go around storing the result as "A","B"?

Comment: If it is string elements, use `gsub('"', "", vect)`

Comment: It does not work as this returns "A, B". I´m looking for "A", "B"

Comment: If you need a quote around, it is just the escape .  You can print with `cat` and check i.e `cat(vect, "\n")`

Comment: My first approach was with cat() yet if stored in a vector (which is what I want to do) I get a NULL (empty) variable

Comment: cat won't return value.  it just prints.  Not sure what you want as expected.  If you want a double quote.  It always prints on the console with that '\`

Comment: I want to read the csv and store the variable "letters" result in a vector as stated in the question. I have been able to print as expected. Yet cannot save it as a vector such as "A","B"

Comment: As i said earlier, it is just the way `print` prints on the console.  You can use the `file` optioin in `cat` to save it in a file

Comment: The \ needs to be in the character vectors that contain `"` other wise it couldn't be interpreted by R. There's no way around this.